# Is it possible to dump the bytecode instrumented by java ASM?

Tags: java, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm

I am learning Java ASM by inserting some simple instructions like `println` into a method. Is it possible to dump the dynamically instrumented bytecode so I can check the correctness?

Comment: Since the result is a byte array, writing it into a file should be a no-brainer.

Comment: I think that works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the TraceClassVisitor to achieve this :

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
ClassVisitor tracer = new TraceClassVisitor(writer,new PrintWriter(sw));
ClassVisitor visitor = new YourClassVisitor(tracer, className);
ClassVisitor checker = new CheckClassAdapter(visitor, true);
cr.accept(checker, ClassReader.EXPAND_FRAMES);
System.out.println(sw.toString());
```